# "Forward" as transitive verb

Tags: email, transitive-verbs

When casually writing email I find myself using *forward* like this:

> I **forwarded him** the email with your info.

Is the above version grammatically correct?

> I **forwarded** the email with your info **to him**

somehow sounds more proper. Given that

> I **sent** you a letter

is structured exactly the same way, it seems like it should work the same with *forward*.

Is this usage accepted? Why might it still sound odd to me, assuming it is in fact correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Barrie England. Both versions sound proper to me. This is probably a new usage of the word *forward* that came about with email use, but since native speakers accept it in both ways, it's fine.

Comment: Before the days of email (yes, I remember them) this same construction was used with physical mail.  To "forward" a letter, you cross out the incorrect address on the envelope, write in the correct address, then give it back to the postman.

Comment: That's right, now that you bring it up I remember it too. But I think then it was always to "forward a letter," in the transitive form, and never just to "forward it."

Answer (score 2):

Sod what's proper. The sentence is written in normal, grammatical English.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that **sod** is an UK slang and not everyone in this community may know what it means. Just in case you'd want to replace it.

Comment: Nah, I love it.

Comment: Around here, when you *sod* something, it means you cover it with grass.

Comment: Yea, so what does it mean in BrEng?

Comment: @Mark: It means, more or less, 'Fuck it'. 'Sod' from 'sodomize', you see. Somehow, and strangely, it's less offensive.

Comment: What a pleasant thing to say.

Comment: Yeh, great, innit?